# Rename WiFi interface

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, debian, network-interface

How to rename WiFi interface on debian

```bsh
root@debian:~# ll /etc/systemd/network/10-persistant-wlan0.link
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 55 Jan 18 12:45 /etc/systemd/network/10-persistant-wlan0.link

root@debian:~# cat /etc/systemd/network/10-persistant-wlan0.link
[Match]
MACAddress=c8:d3:a3:a9:62:4c
[Link]
Name=wlan0

root@debian:~# reboot 

root@debian:~# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens33: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:19:28:66 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.56/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic ens33
       valid_lft 86315sec preferred_lft 86315sec
    inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fe19:2866/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlxc8d3a3a9624c: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c8:d3:a3:a9:62:4c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Comment: Have you tried following the troubleshooting steps outlined in the [systemd.link man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.link.html)?

Comment: Yes,I tried to debug, but it didn't work
But I found a solution that works: 
create its udev file in `/etc/udev/rules.d/10-persistent-network.rules`
and for the content `ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net",ATTR{address}=="c8:d3:a3:a9:62:4c",NAME="wifi0"`